# How could someone calculate the coulomb barrier transparency in 3 dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, probability, fusion

Transparency is also called probability of transmission, or probability of quantum tunneling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With what probability does nuclear fusion occur at energies far below the Coulomb barrier?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73970/)

Comment: I want to find the 3 dimensional probability, in that answer it gives the one dimensional probability.